# MYSQL Select filtered on one column, use index of other column

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have a table looking something like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    atTime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    stuff varchar(100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT myTable_PK PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

The `atTime` column is not indexed.
The `id` column is always in chronological order.
I'd like to select all rows where `id` > x and `atTime` < y.
Is there any way of doing this without doing a full table scan for each select and without adding an index to `atTime`?
Essentially what I want is to tell MYSQL to rely on `id` being chronological to optimize the query.

**Edit:**
Figured out one way of doing it using a subquery but it only made it faster with about 30%:

```
SELECT * from myTable
WHERE id<(  SELECT id FROM myTable
            WHERE atTime>'y'
            ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
            )
AND id>x
```

By themselves these 2 queries are near instantaneous, but together they take quite some time. Why could that be?

Comment: Have you created the table yourself ? Cause I actually don't understand why there is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `TIMESTAMP` while this is set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` by default.

Comment: Haha, neither do I. Somehow accidentally got the auto increment checkbox checked in Dbeaver when creating that DDL. Removed.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do "WHERE id>x and atTime < y"

Comment: Because atTime is not indexed so a full table scan will be made, or at least for all rows with id>x.

Comment: Your subquery needs `INDEX(atTime)`.